# Burn a read-only DVD?

Tags: dvd-burning, copy-protection

I want to burn a DVD with images (JPG,PNG,BMP etc) or video (mpg,mp4 etc.), but I want the DVD to not be copiable onto a PC hard disk; it can only run on a CD/DVD drive.

Comment: You can create an autostart program that the pictures and videos are embedded into the program. However, you would not be able to prevent people from copying raw images/videos off of a media like that.

Comment: I want to burn dvd like we burn data dvd but with only read only attributes and copy/move disabled attributes

Comment: What images are you trying to protect? I think that you're going about it the wrong way. Are you a photographer and looking to provide proofs to a client so that they can make a decision of which pictures they want to purchase. Typically, providing watermarked and low resolution images is sufficient to avoid worrying about stealing the pictures.

Comment: At best, you can prevent them from copying the raw, original files, but if the user can *view* the data, then they can copy/save it. You cannot let them see it without sending the data to them, and if you send it, then they can capture it.

Comment: capturing is ok with me. I want to prevent raw data.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking isn't possible in any practical way.
You can burn a DVD that will play on DVD players, but there's no way to stop someone extracting the data from the DVD.

The only way that this could possibly be done is to create a proprietary format that will only play on DVD players that you have designed with this proprietary format in mind.

Using the standard ways of burning DVDs that are playable on DVD players means that any computer will also be able to play the data back on a computer, which in turn means that the data can be extracted by the computer.